# Can the verb LEARN be followed by a gerund?

Tags: verbs

I've done brief research and found out that usually "learn" is not followed by gerunds but sometimes it is. For example:

**I am learning boxing.**

Is it true? What other gerunds can be used with TO LEARN?

Comment: How can "I am learning shooting big game". be corrected?

Comment: You can. In your example, "boxing" is a noun functioning as object of "learning". "Learning" can take clausal complements, but only infinitivals, not gerund-participials. Thus, we can say "I am learning shooting" but not *"I am learning shooting big game". We need "I am learning to shoot big game". The clausal "I am learning to box" is preferable to "I am learning boxing".

Comment: I answered that in my previous comment; "I am learning to shoot big game".

Comment: There is nothing wrong with "I am learning boxing".

Answer (score 6):

For example: I am learning painting or cooking.

But we generally say: I am learning **to** paint or play piano.

Any gerund denoting something you learn can be used. However, it sounds somewhat immature or childish (to my ear).

When presented with: **I am learning to cook.** versus **I am learning cooking.**, the first sounds more mature.

Any activity, basically, that you learn can be described with a gerund and come after learn.

I'm learning typing. Yep, I am.

But what would I actually say in my every day usage?

- I'm learning to type.

Call if what you like if you don't like my distinction. ***It is definitely less elegant.***

Comment: Do you mean the first?

Comment: But isn't it natural to say "I am learning boxing!"?

Comment: I think your final sentence was supposed to end with *the **first (to cook)** sounds more mature*, given you said earlier that it's the ***gerund (cooking)*** that sounds childish to you.

Comment: ...but I *don't* think it's right to just split the two possibilities into ***infinitive =  correct / "mature", gerund = incorrect / "childish"***. Which form is idiomatic after ***to learn*** varies according to the ***specific*** verb, so it's normally *He learnt **to write***, but *He learnt **fencing***. We just think of the non-idiomatic version as "childish", and of the two non-idiomatic versions, we're more likely to notice children erroneously using the gerund where they "should" have used the infinitive.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica, what are the ones which can be used as gerunds? Boxing, fencing... what else?

Comment: @user1425: There's nothing *wrong* with using the gerund for *He learnt boxing*, but in fact that one isn't common compared to the infinitive *He learnt **to box***. I chose ***fencing*** as my example because that was one I was pretty sure would be more common as a gerund (which I confirmed using NGrams). I can tell you without checking that *learned **gardening*** will be much more common than ***...to garden***, but I can't rattle off a long list of activities that are more likely to be referenced using infinitive or continuous / gerund after ***to learn***. No can I explain ***why***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica What is common are activity verbs: gardening, fencing, boxing, sewing, dancing.  Also, what's with the past tense? Call it what you like, I personally, **would never say** I learnt cooking at school. I would say: I learned to cook at school. Why? Because of what I said in my answer which I stick by. Thank you for messing up my answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica What is common are activity verbs: gardening, fencing, boxing, sewing, dancing.  Also, what's with the past tense? Call it what you like, I personally, **would never say** I learnt cooking at school. I would say: I learned to cook at school. Why? Because of what I said in my answer which I stick by. Call it unsophisticated. Any activity that can be learned can go as a gerund after learn.

Answer (score 2):

The verb "to learn" is supposed to be followed by an infinitive, which is stated by many grammar books that have a list of verbs followed by a gerund or an infinitive:

- He was learning to shoot.
- She started learning to play the piano.

In some cases a gerund is acceptable after "to learn", however a closely related verb that can be used instead of "to learn" and which is followed by a gerund is "to practise":

- He practised shooting.
- She practised playing the piano.

Comment: If by 'gerund'. you mean '(gerundial) **noun**', then i agree.

Comment: practice and learn are not the same thing. Learn French = Verb + object Learn diving. Verb+ object. Any learning activity can come after learn.

Comment: @BillJ Yes indeed, engineering, fishing, gaming

Comment: @Lambie I can't deny but I often hear "learn how to dive", "learn how to swim" instead

Comment: In, for example, "I don't know [how to dive/swim]" the bracketed element is an interrogative infinitival clause. It has a deontic meaning, cf. "I don't know how I should dive/swim". "Dive" is of course a plain (infinitival) form.